# server not managing to send ump message to client

Tags: c, udp

I'm currently working on a UDP audio server/client implementation where the server receives a file name from the client and sends the details of the audio file in response. The server receives the file name and opens it and acquires all of the necessary information, yet fails to send to the client I didn't manage to figure out what was wrong with it so I would appreciate any sort of suggestions to dealing with this.

Client:

```
len = sendto(sockfd, filename, strlen(filename), 0, (struct                   
 sockaddr*)&server_address,sizeof(server_address));
 //Sends the filename to server successfully

 if(len < 0){
    printf("could not send filename\n");
    return 1;
}
printf("1\n");
recvfrom(sockfd, s_rate, 1024, 0, NULL,  NULL);
recvfrom(sockfd, s_size, 1024, 0, NULL,  NULL);
recvfrom(sockfd, channels, 1024, 0, NULL,  NULL);
recvfrom(sockfd, content, 1024, 0, NULL, NULL);
printf("2\n");
 //Waits for information about audiofile from server
```

Server:

```
read_size = recvfrom(socket_desc, file_name, 
1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, 
 &client_address_len);
//Receives filename successfully from client. Opens the 
file gets information from it and then attempts to send 
the information as a string:

sprintf(rate, "%d", ra);
sprintf(size, "%d", s);
sprintf(ch, "%d", c);
printf("rate: %s, size: %s, ch: %s\n", rate, size, ch);
int err = sendto(socket_desc, rate, strlen(rate), 0, (struct 
sockaddr *) &client_address,
sizeof(client_address));
if(err < 0){
  printf("could not send rate\n");
  }
 err = sendto(socket_desc, size, strlen(size), 0, (struct 
  sockaddr *) &client_address,
 sizeof(client_address));
 if(err < 0){
 printf("could not send size\n");
  }
err = sendto(socket_desc, ch, strlen(ch), 0, (struct 
 sockaddr *) &client_address,
 sizeof(client_address));
  if(err < 0){
printf("could not send channels\n");
```

I hope this is enough information.
Edit:
The recvfrom function stops the program until it receives the package and the sendto function returns -1 on error. Here is some of the code for the server that shows how it creates and binds the socket:

```
int socket_desc, read_size, client_address_len, audio; int 
*s_rate, *s_size, *channels; struct sockaddr_in server; 
struct sockaddr_in client_address; char file_name[1024]; 
 char content[1024], rate[1024], size[1024], ch[1024]; // 
 malloc(sizeof(int), 1) // free(s_rate) s_rate = (int *) 
  malloc(sizeof(int)); s_size = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)); 
channels = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)); socket_desc = 
 socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP); 
  if(socket_desc < 0){ printf("error creating socket\n"); 
  return 1; } – Omri Ram 6 mins ago   delete
 server.sin_family = AF_INET; server.sin_port = 
 htons(2018); server.sin_addr.s_addr = 
htonl(INADDR_ANY); if(bind(socket_desc, (struct 
 sockaddr * )&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){ printf("error 
 binding socket \n"); return 1; }
```

This is coded on Ubuntu (Linux virtual machine)

Comment: How are `socket_desc`,  `client_address_len`, `client_address` `rate`, `size` and `ch` defined and initialised.

Comment: Same question for `s_rate`, `s_size`, `channels`and `content`.

Comment: "*yet fails to send to the client*" which you conclude from exactly what? Many library functions set `errno` on failure. You want print it and/or use `perror()` to nicely print a text description of the failure..

Comment: Please do not extend your question in comments. Add stuff to the question as update.

Comment: S_rate and the others are character arrays that will store the packet sent to them. Rate size and ch are pointers to the array that has the information to be sent to the client

Comment: And it would be very nice if you'd made live easier for your fellow coders by properly indenting the code you them.

Comment: Is there a typo in the title, as this is the 3rd google match for "ump message"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client_address_len` needs to be initialised to size of the `struct` being passed to `sendto()`.

And if not on windows it needs to be of type `socklen_t` not `int`.

So its definition and initialisation would look like this;

```
  struct sockaddr_in client_address; 
  socklen_t client_address_len = sizeof client_address;
```

---

Another pitfall is that the server sends strings:

```
   ... = sendto(socket_desc, rate, strlen(rate), ...
```

and the client (tries to) receive the data as binary:

```
   int * s_rate;
   ...
   s_rate = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
   ...
   recvfrom(sockfd, s_rate, ...
```

(same for `s_size` and `channels`)

Server and client do not speak the same language. A route into disaster.